# Use same backing bean object with same value in two Different JSF page

Tags: jsf, facelets

I have one jsf page and popup other jsf page from it.

Now i get all value reset from backing bean in popup page.

please help..

Answer (score 1):

make it `@SessionScoped` if jsf2.0 or `<scope>session</scope>` if older

This bean will be alive & accessible through out the session

Comment: i face this problem for all bean...i coldn't make scope for all bean as session..i have already used <t:saveState>..still not working :( i m using JSF1.2

Comment: Then you could use `rich:modalpanel` or something like this instead a new popup window

Comment: i cant change view...as i m using facelets..it would affect whole project.

Comment: `<t:saveState>` what exact issue with ?

Comment: i can't use all settled properties from backing bean which already set by parent page..now i popup other page using link..so whatever i have set properties in backing bean that all would reset in popup..so might it would create new object for backing bean so i just want to use same properties with value from parent page as well child page of jsf...